# Description of socio-demographics for a cluster analysis

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I did an cluster analysis, with the outcome of three clusters based on a couple of variables. Now I want to describe these three clusters in terms of their socio-demographics.

I put each cluster into a seperate dataframe together with the socio-demographics (passive variables). I got a question from my teacher, asking me to provide some percentages and distribution on age/ gender/ area and educational level.

Since I just started programming I find it hard to think as a professional data analysist. So, is ther a data analyst who can help me out haha!

thanks in advance!

Already divided the segment_data into three dataframes; for each segment a seperate dataframe. Now I want to know the percentages: how many are male or female, what % lives in area 3 etc

Comment: Provide some reproducible data from one of the data.frames using `dput(head(df, 15))` and paste the output into your question. You did not need to split out the clusters since R has functions such as `aggregate()` that will generate statistics by group.